# Kendo Grid Drag and Drop - Can I drag a complete row

Tags: kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-grid

I am trying to achieve the functionality of drag and drop in a grid. I am so far successful in dragging a specific column However the UI requirements are that, I should be able to drag a complete row. Is this possible? If Yes, how?

Thanks,
Abinash

Comment: Drag between a grid and the same grid or different grid? I.e. sorting rows or moving rows between grids?

Comment: please add related code...

Comment: Hi,I want to drag one row and drop it some where else in the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to comment, but if you are looking to drag and drop rows within a grid, that is possible through the Sortable integration to the Grid:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/integration-grid

Comment: Hi,I want to drag one row and drop it some where else in the screen.

Comment: I want to drag and drop in different Grid with hierarchical data..
https://jsfiddle.net/ravituvar/0xe9u4g6/

The Drag and drop is working fine but the row is not dropping in Detail row in destination grid.